# Jquery Tooltipster function to show the content when user hovers over it

Tags: jquery, tooltip, tooltipster

I m a beginner at Tooltipster functions
Below is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>attr demo</title>
  <style>

  div {
    color: red;
    font-size: 24px;
  }

  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js"></script>
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.tooltip').tooltipster();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="my-tooltip"> 
        This div has a tooltip with HTML when you hover over it!
</div>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $( ".my-tooltip" ).tooltip({ content: "Awesome title!" });
            alert("dsad");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But the output is shows only this:

> This div has a tooltip with HTML when you hover over it!

Also in console, there is error at line 30:`$( ".my-tooltip" ).tooltip({ content: "Awesome title!" });`
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Help please!!! how to use tooltipster functions and use them..?

Comment: smiley in the question, srsly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69vhZ/2/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#my-tooltip').tooltipster({
            content: $('<strong class="tooltip">Awesome title!</strong>')
        });
});
```

Just as an alternative, Jquery UI also supports **[.tooltip()](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)**. Its easy to use.
In that case,

```
$( ".selector" ).tooltip({ content: "Awesome title!" });
```

will work, but you have to include jQuery UI.

Comment: can u tell me how to include jQuery UI in my html code.?

Comment: just as you include jquery `<script>`- **[jQueryUI download](http://jqueryui.com/download/)**  or `<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>`